# Contacts page - use List or build layout with standard Views

Tags: java, android, listview, material-design, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to recreate a page like screenshot below. There are some approaches that comes to my mind but I can't decide which one would be the best.

1. Create a `listview` and add each row layout accordingly to it.
2. use a `constraintlayout` and specify how each element would be placed against the other one.

Which one you would prefer or any other approach that you think would work better for a details screen. I think it needs to be said that this details screen shows many info about the place and all of them are not with same height. some of them might have a need for a special layout with more height.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely the first approach, but I would not recommend you using ListView. Instead you should use RecyclerView. It is case were you should use it:

The items are the same (almost) and your layout file will be clear and contain only one View - RecyclerView. It will be dynamic, so you may have here  5 or 25 items (contact details), the only thing you should do is add ContactModelItem to your adapter, that's it.

On the other hand, if you implement ConstraintLayout, your XML file will be huge, and very difficult to maintain with such many constraints, dependent on each other. Even from design view it will be difficult to maintain it.